# How to show multiple events per day on month view?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

Right now, when I add more than 1 event to the calendar, it shows +2. I want to show up to 4 events per day in the month view and then after the 4th event show the +2, +3, etc. If that makes sense. Sorry very new to coding. I am using FullCalendar.io

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Did you spend any time with the documentation? Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `dayMaxEventRows: true` set (v5)

or it is set to a specific integer, i.e. `dayMaxEventRows : 1`

Either remove it or set it to false

```
dayMaxEventRows: false
```

on previous versions the setting was named `eventLimit`